# How to install different versions of python on centOS 8?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, centos8

I have python3.6 installed on CentOS Linux release 8.3

```
[fnord@fnord fnord]$ ls -ls /usr/bin/python*
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Aug 31  2020 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
12 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 8224 Aug 31  2020 /usr/bin/python2.7
 0 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   25 Jun 24  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   31 Nov  4  2020 /usr/bin/python3.6 -> /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   17 Nov  4  2020 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> python3.6m-config
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   32 Nov  4  2020 /usr/bin/python3.6m -> /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6m
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   39 Nov  4  2020 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6m-config
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   46 Nov  4  2020 /usr/bin/python3.6m-x86_64-config -> /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6m-x86_64-config
 0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   32 Mar 16  2021 /usr/bin/python3-config -> /etc/alternatives/python3-config
[fnord@fnord fnord]$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
[fnord@fnord fnord]$cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011
```

How would I install python3.7, python3.8,... on the same system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dnf` e.g.

```
dnf install python38
```

Then you can use [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to manage which version of python you're using for a particular project